# Possible way to add multiple start_boundary for community.windows.win_scheduled_task

Tags: ansible, scheduled-tasks, ansible-2.x

Been trying to find ways to make a trigger to work by setting a schedule task to run at 3 specific times but have not had any luck.

Current code fails as seen below.

> community.windows.win_scheduled_task:

Code:

```yaml
- name: Create task with multiple triggers
  community.windows.win_scheduled_task:
    name: TriggerTask
    path: \Custom
    actions:
    - path: cmd.exe
    triggers:
    - type: daily
    - start_boundary: '2022-01-01T05:00:00','2022-01-01T11:00:00','2022-01-01T17:00:00'
    username: SYSTEM
    state: present
    enabled: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems to point to the fact that `triggers` is a list that can accept multiple value.

I don't have a Windows host to test it, but, a possible way to achieve it that kind of match what the documentation is indicating would be to have a list under the `trigger` parameters, like this:

```yaml
triggers:
  - type: daily
    start_boundary: '2022-01-01T05:00:00'
  - type: daily
    start_boundary: '2022-01-01T11:00:00'
  - type: daily
    start_boundary: '2022-01-01T17:00:00'
```

Ending up with this task:

```yaml
- name: Create task with multiple triggers
  community.windows.win_scheduled_task:
    name: TriggerTask
    path: \Custom
    actions:
      - path: cmd.exe
    triggers:
      - type: daily
        start_boundary: '2022-01-01T05:00:00'
      - type: daily
        start_boundary: '2022-01-01T11:00:00'
      - type: daily
        start_boundary: '2022-01-01T17:00:00'
    username: SYSTEM
    state: present
    enabled: yes
```